# How do I make a sprite move to another position using vectors

Tags: sprites, vector, python, pygame

Ok, so far I have made the sprite move to a mouse position. But I got a question, does anyone know how to make a sprite move by itself without the use of a mouseclick from Point a to point b using vectors? In which then the sprite stops after reaching point B.

```
def calcMoveVector(self):
    movetopos = self.posto
    currentpos = self.rect.center
    directtoX = movetopos[0]-currentpos[0]
    directtoY = movetopos[1]-currentpos[1]

    vect = pygame.math.Vector2(10, 10)
    if vect.length() > 0: self.vector = vect.normalize()
    return vect

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            r = pygame.rect.Rect(mpos[0],mpos[1],10,10)
            buttons=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

            if buttons[0]==True:
                c = pygame.color.THECOLORS["green2"]
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,c,r)
                monster.posto = mpos
                monster.state = Monster.MOVETO
                monster.speed=3
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a function which operates on `self.posto`.  So the relevant code is in how you set that property.  The code you included <del>should work just fine</del> is broken, but you simply give it a different destination.

And as you might expect, you have literally infinite options for how you set that destination vector.

**Edit:**

The code you posted won't work.  You go through the effort of calculating the direction, but for some reason you stop using it halfway through your function.  It should read:

```
vect = pygame.math.Vector2(directtoX, directtoY)
```

Or, since [the docs say `pygame.math.Vector2` supports "numerical operations"](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) (python-speak for operator overloading?), you could condense the previous two lines, as well:

```
movetopos = self.posto
currentpos = self.rect.center
vect = movetopos - currentpos  // also a vector, via subtraction
```

Comment: ok I see, I was able to get the sprite doing mouseclicks. But for some reason in vect = pygame.math.vector2(10,10) i keep getting an error in which the module object has no attribute with math.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you about that, because `pygame.math` clearly exists.  It sounds like an import problem, which lays elsewhere in your code.  I'm afraid I don't have the python knowledge to help you fix it (and it wouldn't be a game-dev issue anyway, hence off-topic).

Comment: oh ok yeah I changed it to vect = pygame.math.Vector2(directtoX, directtoY) but I still seem to get an error with the no attribute with math. I am going to see if it is something to with my installed program.

Comment: well I think I will need to figure that out later. But here is my other source. Which so far uses the mouseclick. Do I need to alter any of these to make the sprite move by itself?

Comment: if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                r = pygame.rect.Rect(mpos[0],mpos[1],10,10)
                buttons=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

                if buttons[0]==True:
                    c = pygame.color.THECOLORS["green2"]
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,c,r)
                    monster.posto = mpos
                    monster.state = Monster.MOVETO